# CURL closing connection 0

Tags: curl

I'm doing a 'CURL' and this looks like it finishes right, but I'm doubting if really finishes right or not.

My doubt's about that 'CURL' closes the connection before the last tag. Is this normal? even if the result of the connection is zero.

```
* upload completely sent off: 689 out of 689 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gSOAP/2.7
< Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 172
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: close
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XMLResponse>
        <ResponseCode>123456789e</ResponseCode>
        <TranID>Data123456789a</TranID>
        <Dynamic>123456789f</Dynamic>
* Closing connection 0
</XMLResponse>
```

Before tag "`</XMLResponse>`" appears "*** Closing connection 0**", why closing connection not appear after the last tag?

Best regards,